Making living screens “And active camouflage”
In my story humanity focuses more on genetic engineering to produce advanced technologies. This engineering ranges from bioluminescent lights to giant living space pods that are self sustaining. But but another technology they made using genetic engineering are screens and active camouflage
Although used for different purposes, they both have a similar origin. Both technologies are made from cultivated cephalopod cells that contain chromatophores. The cephalopod screens are controlled using electrical shocks to manipulate the skins color patterns to create images. The active camouflage is a large humanoid structure that is worn by a soldier “It resembles a clear skin tight suit”. The soldier is able to change its color and texture thanks to electrical interfacing.
But as I was writing my story I thought to myself. Is technology like this possible?

Skin tight might make this almost useless. Maybe a cloak or poncho?

I sort-of did the cephalopod engineering bit. I worked for Canon in the nineties, and proposed a 4-colour display using electrostrictive gels inspired by what squids do. It was going to be called 'squideo'. It could probably have managed 15 frames a second on the technology of the day. CRTs were practically the only display in those days. LCDs had poor refresh rates, poor contrast, and dead pixels. There were over twenty different display technologies that might have made it.
My guess is that people could have done this already for camouflage if there was sufficient will to do so. But there hasn't been the will, and maybe there won'e ever be.
Let's be clear what we are taking about here. We are not going to make some Harry Potter 'cloak of invisibility'. Making yourself invisible from different angles is very hard. If we could do that, the other side could make better tools for seeing, and we would be back where we started. The best we can hope for is to blend in with our surroundings and not draw attention to ourselves.
So, how do you disguise a tank? You could paint it the right colour. Tanks are repainted to match their deployment zone. Top that off with some camouflage webbing to soften the edges. The heat of the tank might show up. You could use angled mirrors or bent Fresnel lenses. That would get more of the wavelengths right. Here is a video of one. It doesn't work from all angles, but it can look pretty magic if you chose your viewing direction carefully. You can get some of that stuff if you take apart an old LCD.
Is the BAE adaptive camouflage a boondoggle? I don't think so. You can get a lot of display technology for the cost of an armoured personnel carrier. It would be negligent not to test the limits of what you can do. You don't have to fool all of the people all of the time: if you can look like a car for a few seconds, that may confuse an enemy with a rocket launcher long enough for you to target them.

Well.... Sort of
Now - the bit I cant answer is the whole cephalopod Genetic engineering part - but that sounds like a reasonably plausible technology, perhaps needing a teeny bit of handwaiving - but no more than say the Heisenburg compensator that makes Star Trek teleporters work.
The actual theory of adaptive Camouflage - that is science fact - for example here is a video of BAE Systems trialling Adaptive Infrared camouflage for tanks:
Here
or visual techniques like this one
All-in-all - the basic theory of using a colour changing organism to create a living cloak that could be manipulated to blend into the background - so long as you set your story a little bit in the future so it is believable (probably around 100 years minimum) - I think this is a perfectly sounding plausible tech.

This kind of a thing is perfectly possible to do with mundane technology, let alone with future biotech.
The issue is, doing it well enough to fool human eyesight is tricky.
In order for the Camouflage suit to project an image of what is behind it, and thus help the user blend in, it has to have an advanced system of cameras (eyes?) to actually capture the image or video of what is behind it. The eyes/cameras themselves though, cannot be camouflaged because they need to capture light. This is the first problem.
The second problem is that the system of eyes/cameras would have to be pretty much perfect, in speed, accuracy, angle, resolution and frame-coherence, so that the camo-pattern generated out of it is not just a crude collage of the surroundings that looks wrapped around a person-shape, but a seamless illusion. Human eyes evolved to see 3d very well, so it is difficult to fool us when a 3d object tries to camo as its 2d background, and even worse when it tries to camo as its 3d background. The edges between the outline of the suit and the background are dead giveaway. Shadows and light rays breaking around the suited person are another.
And finally, such a suit would not fool an infrared camera, or someone with night-vision  goggles. Even a strong enough flashlight will carve them out of the background.
Simply put: such a suit is theoretically possible, but would be easily defeated by relatively simple technological counters, so it would have limited utility.
